# automatic slideshow stopping at last image

Tags: javascript, css, image, slider, slideshow

thanks in advance for your time. I decided to tweak the automatic slideshow from W3Schools (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) in order to get a Y-axis moving transition instead of opacity only but I broke the continuity of the slider. I would like it to automatically restart from the first image after the last image, instead of stopping completely. This is the code, I'll appreciate any help, should be easy for someone knowing what he's doing (not like me). Thank you

```js
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  
  
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   
    slides[i].style.opacity = "1"; 
    
  }
  
  
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
     
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  
    

  
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
  
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none; position: absolute;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  
}


/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from { opacity: .1; transform: translateY(-100%); } 
  to { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  
  <img src="https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/colors/bright-blue-color-solid-background-1920x1080.png" style="width:100%">
  
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  
  <img src="https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/colors/charcoal-color-solid-background-1920x1080.png" style="width:100%">
 
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
 
  <img src="https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/colors/teal-color-solid-background-1920x1080.png" style="width:100%">
  
</div>

</div>
<br>



<script>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the transition happens when element becomes 'display:block' (I would have made it another way, using an `.active` class) - I have decided to set 'display:none' for the next element so it will be shown next.

Also fixed an issue with z-index so I keep bring the current active above else.

```js
let slideIndex = 0;
let zIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");


  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

    slides[i].style.opacity = "1";

  }


  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

  // this is all quite patchy, 
  // but it works if you have more than 2 slides
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.zIndex = zIndex++;
  slides[slideIndex % slides.length].style.display = "none";

  setTimeout(showSlides, 1000); // Change image every 2 seconds

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .1;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">

      <img src="https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/colors/bright-blue-color-solid-background-1920x1080.png" style="width:100%">

    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">

      <img src="https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/colors/charcoal-color-solid-background-1920x1080.png" style="width:100%">

    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">

      <img src="https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/colors/teal-color-solid-background-1920x1080.png" style="width:100%">

    </div>

  </div>
```